# Cognos 10.2.2 configuration for sample and framework manager

Tags: cognos

I am installing and configuring cognos 10.2.2. I have successfully installed and configured server and IIS. But I am facing issue in configuring sample and frame work manager.

Issue: In Cognos configuration I am getting error in the step "Generating cryptograhic information" while testing. The error is below

"[Cryptography]
[ ERROR ] CAM-CRP-1140 The HTTP result code '500' was returned from the server."

Please note this Cognos Configuration is for Sample and framework manager not for server.

Please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try to telnet to the port your dispatcher is running on?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I can telnet my Cogos server on the port 9300

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually due to you attaching to a data source with encryption keys different than the ones stored locally in the Cognos directory. The solution is to get them synced. This IBM document explains how:

[How to Regenerate Cryptographic Keys](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21383421)